# How to make horizontal jquery dropdown navigation bar 100% width of page

Tags: jquery, html

here is what I have for my navigation bar right now: 
[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cupekaxu/26/edit)

I can't seem to get it so that the navigation bar expands to full width of the screen, regardless of whether the window is minimized or not. Setting the navigation bar width (#navbar) to 100% doesn't do the trick.

Comment: You can do womething like that: http://jsbin.com/gopanuti/1/edit
I put the navigation bar in a container and that's this container which has a 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it, playing around with your code.

I moved the background color to the `#navbar` and then made it a width of 100%. You ALMOST had it working, the only thing you need to do is to put a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` element after the list `<li>`. (this is an issue with floated elements, you need to add something like this to correct their behavior that they don't affect the dimentions of their parent element anymore)

The other thing you can do is just give the navigation bar a height manually (43px looked fine here).